# Get real column with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, graphql, apollo-server

I would like to know how can I have a real column (code) on return in my request.

> I have always the same **code** from Peoples table, and not the real **code** : it's the parent code and not the child code.

Currently I have 4 tables:

```
| Peoples (id, code) <- this code
| PeopleFriends (id, fk_user_id, fk_friend_id)
| PeopleTranslations (id, user_name, fk_people_id, fk_language_id)
| Languages (id, code)
```

With this data:

```
Peoples:
[id: 1, code: HUMAN1]
[id: 2, code: HUMAN2]
[id: 3, code: HUMAN3]
[id: 4, code: HUMAN4]
[id: 5, code: HUMAN5]

PeopleFriends:
[id: 1, fk_user_id: 1, fk_friend_id: 2]
[id: 2, fk_user_id: 1, fk_friend_id: 3]
[id: 3, fk_user_id: 1, fk_friend_id: 4]
[id: 4, fk_user_id: 1, fk_friend_id: 5]

PeopleTranslations:
[id: 1, username: "username human 1", fk_people_id: 1, fk_language_id: 1]
[id: 2, username: "username human 2", fk_people_id: 2, fk_language_id: 1]
[id: 3, username: "username human 3", fk_people_id: 3, fk_language_id: 1]
[id: 4, username: "username human 4", fk_people_id: 4, fk_language_id: 1]
[id: 5, username: "username human 5", fk_people_id: 5, fk_language_id: 1]

Languages:
[id: 1, code: "EN"]
```

If I execute this request:

```
SELECT pt.fk_people_id AS id, p.code, pt.user_name FROM Peoples p 
INNER JOIN PeopleFriends pf ON p.id = pf.fk_user_id 
INNER JOIN PeopleTranslations pt ON pf.fk_friend_id = pt.fk_people_id 
INNER JOIN Languages l ON pt.fk_language_id = l.id 
WHERE l.code = 'EN'
AND p.id = 1
```

I have this result:

```
[
TextRow {
    id: 2,
    code: 'HUMAN1', <--- I would like HUMAN2, not parent code
    user_name: 'username human 2',
},
TextRow {
    id: 3,
    code: 'HUMAN1', <--- I would like HUMAN3, not parent code
    user_name: 'username human 3',
},
TextRow {
    id: 4,
    code: 'HUMAN1', <--- I would like HUMAN4, not parent code
    user_name: 'username human 4',
},
TextRow {
    id: 5,
    code: 'HUMAN1', <--- I would like HUMAN5, not parent code
    user_name: 'username human 5',
}
]
...
```

I have always the same code "HUMAN1", and not the real code "HUMAN2", "HUMAN3", "HUMAN4"

It's the code to p.id = 1...

I tried to add p.code, but I have the same error.

Comment: *I have this result :* Show source data which produces this output. Explain why it "must be ...".

Comment: @Akina thx for your comment, I updated my post. I would like the "child code" and not the "parent code"

Comment: Please post tables structures and sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Current form is not applicable for testing purposes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pt.fk_people_id AS id, 
       p1.code, 
       pt.user_name 
FROM       Peoples p 
INNER JOIN PeopleFriends pf      ON p.id = pf.fk_user_id 
INNER JOIN Peoples p1            ON p1.id = pf.fk_friend_id
INNER JOIN PeopleTranslations pt ON pf.fk_friend_id = pt.fk_people_id 
INNER JOIN Languages l           ON pt.fk_language_id = l.id 
WHERE l.code = 'EN'
  AND p.id = 1
```

Taken into account the condition in WHERE the query may be simplified to

```
SELECT pt.fk_people_id AS id, 
       p1.code, 
       pt.user_name 
FROM       PeopleFriends pf
INNER JOIN Peoples p1            ON p1.id = pf.fk_friend_id
INNER JOIN PeopleTranslations pt ON pf.fk_friend_id = pt.fk_people_id 
INNER JOIN Languages l           ON pt.fk_language_id = l.id 
WHERE l.code = 'EN'
  AND pf.fk_user_id = 1
```

Comment: Perfect @Akina ! Thx !